# Meteor: How to escape "template" as code in spacebar?

Tags: meteor, spacebars

I'd like to literally display a template as code in a meteor app. Something like below:

```
<template name="current-template">
  <pre>
    <code>
       <template name="template-should-display-as-code">
         {{> TMCODE shouldDisplayAsIs}}
       </template>
    </code>
  </pre>
</template>
```

The template inside the code section should be displayed as code. It shouldn't refer to another template. It is illegal syntax anyway.

Is there anyway to achieve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help..
Display source code in meteor applications
http://www.meteormade.com/display-source-code-in-meteor-applications